# How to check equality with combination of two columns data in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity

public class Employee{

private String Id;
private String preId;

}

I've a Entity like above and i want to get the search results on the combination of both fields. (preId+Id)
```

Is it possible through Restrictions eq method to verify the above combination of fields with my searching input value?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can add 2 restrictions for the Id and preId as follows.

```
public Employee getEmployee(Session session) {
    Criteria crt = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", "1"));
    crt.add(Restrictions.eq("preId", "123"));
    return (Employee ) crt.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but actually my searching value contains both values(preId+Id)..   For ex: preId=TH11 and Id=50. and my input value contains TH1150. Now i need to check equality of input value with concatenation of two columns values.

Comment: So you have to split your value and check for the equality.